# Android - Can we use SharedViewModel and ViewModel in the same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have a `Fragment` that requires a `SharedViewModel` to handle general flows. However, this `Fragment` also has specific logic that should be encapsulated in a separate `ViewModel`.

It is a good practice to implement a `SharewViewModel` and `ViewModel` in the same `Fragment`?

**Implementation example:**

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
private val sharedViewModel: BaseViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

Comment: I see no particular problem with it. I do not know how you define "a good practice" though, so IMHO this question is dancing on the edge of "opinion-based".

Comment: I totally accept your opinion and yes, the question is close to being more of a debate than a doubt. @CommonsWare thank you.